# Saving data to a text file using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, webserver

I found a script to write the contents of a textbox to a text file, and show the download link.

But now I need help with modifying this code to save the text files in a specific location in the server once the button is clicked.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
        window.onload=function(){
            (function () {
                var textFile = null,
                makeTextFile = function (text) {
                    var data = new Blob([text], {type: 'text/plain'});
                    // If we are replacing a previously generated file we need to
                    // manually revoke the object URL to avoid memory leaks.
                    if (textFile !== null) {
                        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(textFile);
                    }
                    textFile = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
                    return textFile;
                };

                var create = document.getElementById('create'),
                    textbox = document.getElementById('textbox');

                create.addEventListener('click', function () {
                    var link = document.getElementById('downloadlink');
                    link.href = makeTextFile(textbox.value);
                    link.style.display = 'block';
                }, false);
            })();
        }//]]> 
        </script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="textbox">Type something here</textarea>
    <button id="create">Create file</button>
    <a download="info.txt" id="downloadlink" style="display: none">Download</a>

    <script>
    // tell the embed parent frame the height of the content
    if (window.parent && window.parent.parent){
        window.parent.parent.postMessage(["resultsFrame", {
            height: document.body.getBoundingClientRect().height,
            slug: "qm5AG"
        }], "*")
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Please advise.

Comment: You should send the text to the server and do what you want on your backend code.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to learn backend development for server side practices. A client cant make any modification to the server without a backend in place. (That would be a huge security hole!) I would suggest learning NodeJS here: https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/

Once you become more familiar and think you are ready to pick up this project again send me a direct message and I will point you in the right direction.